# Can paint on a wall considered to be a thin film?

Tags: semiconductor-physics, material-science, optical-materials

In know that general thin films are as thin as few microns to nanometres and have technical and optical uses. But can a dry paint on wall be considered the simplest example of thin films? I mean its a lot thicker than the conventional thin films. But still has optical and surface protection uses. I just, in summary, want to ask is dry, solid, layer of paint on wall a valid example of thin layers.

Comment: From an engineering point of view, it is definitely not. Thin films (as defined in engineering) are formed by molecular scale processes like sputtering or evaporation. Materials applied in the solid or liquid phase, like paint, are considered thick films.

Comment: @ThePhoton - so soap bubbles aren’t a thin film? Spin-on layers can’t be thin films? Graphene layers aren’t thin films?

Answer (score 0):

"Thin" is not a concept well defined by itself. Asking if something can be considered thin, without a precise context, is like asking if a car can be considered "fast"; well it is fast compared to a horse probably, but it is not "fast" enough to be considered a relativistic object.

Your question cannot be properly answer without a specification from you on what do you consider "thin" in this context.